# Unable to get a pdf file from executing pyreport

Tags: python, pyreport

We have been asked to generate a report using `pyreport`, but anytime I run the command `pyreport last.py` in command prompt I get these feedback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pyreport-script.py", line 9, in <module>
     load_entry_point('pyreport==0.3.4c', 'console_scripts', 'pyreport')()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreport-0.3.4c-py2.7.egg\pyreport\pyreport.py", line 52, in commandline_call
     pyfile = open(args[0],"r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'last.py'
```

Please help me solve this problem. i also already have latex installed on my computer does it have anything to do with this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you run script from folder with `last.py`?

Comment: how do i run script from folder

Comment: Ok, you can run it from the same place, but provide full name to the file: `pyreport C:\Path\to\my\last.py`

Comment: @Abdul Thanks I had the same problem, your question helped me in finding a solution